# Sunspot Solr handling a boolean logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

Can sunspot handle a logic having AND and OR operators?

And Sunspot is using the dismax request handler where minimum_match field is used to implement OR queries/ AND queries

Now the problem is when we need to combine AND and OR operators together. How to implement the same.

```
text = "Hot Air Balloon"

search = Video.solr_search, :minimum_match => text.size do
  fulltext text do
    fields :title
  end
end
```

I need something like HOT AND AIR OR BALLOON

Comment: Is there some logic behind HOT AND AIR OR BALLOON? This is an example, can you make it more general?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited number of possible text combination, you can force OR with any_of:

```
text1=["hot","air"]
text2=["balloon"]

search = Video.search do
    any_of do
        fulltext text1, fields: :title
        fulltext text2, fields: :title
    end
end
```

Comment: tried it and get this  undefined method `fulltext' for #<Sunspot::DSL::Scope:0x0000000d0ba510>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/util.rb:241:in `__proxy_method__'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/util.rb:236:in `method_missing'

Comment: Try strings instead of arrays, like text1="hot air", text2="balloon"

Comment: Still not working. I guess it does not work in the scope of any_of

Comment: Yeah, must be it. Otherwise syntax is ok. Check this page if it applies to you: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Setting-up-classes-for-search-and-indexing

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, any_of and all_of only works for scalar fields (strings, integers), not for fulltext search (see documentation, it says about these two methods in context of scalar fields). If you want to achieve such effect on one field, you have to create your query manually:

```
fulltext "Hot AND Air OR Balloon" do
    fields :title
end
```

It gives you a query to Solr:

```
 q=Hot AND Air OR Balloon&qf=title&rows=1&start=0
```

I didn't test it but this should also work:

```
"+hot +air ballon"
```

'+' sign means that word is mandatory. 'Balloon' can be left without any operator as the default for dismax is 'OR' operator (you can check your settings for default operator in schema.xml, solrQueryParser node).

Answer (score 0):

As of version [2.2.0](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/487), sunspot_solr defaults to [edismax](https://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser) parser, which supports queries using AND, OR, NOT, -, and +.

```
text = "HOT AND AIR OR BALLOON"

search = Video.search do
  fulltext text
end
```